# Automate function + Database Google Cloud Platform

Tags: database, automation, google-cloud-platform

I have to maintain a database on the Google Cloud Platform and along with it put in a script(preferably in python) that is automated to put in new values from an API on a daily basis.

I'm confused as to how to go about this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please describe your environment. For example, are you using GKE with your DB running in a container? Or just MySQL in a VM? Does it have to be free or can it cost a modest VM ($25) per month?

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the [App Engine platform](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) which allow you to deploy a python application. It can be set to simply await instructions from your API or fetch the information directly. With the help of [CRON](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron), you can schedule task that should take care of pushing the object within your Database.

Another option would be the [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/use-cases/). Currently Cloud Functions only handles the Nodejs runtime but it allows you to run a backend application that only runs when triggered. With a simple HTTP trigger from your API, your function should handle the data received and organize it before storing it in your Database.

Other options are available like Cloud Endpoints, Database (Spanner, Cloud SQL, Cloud PostgreSQL, Bigtable,) API, etc. All depends of semantics of your project (Will it be run only once daily, how fast does the whole operation has to be completed, etc.). I would suggest to review all of Google CLoud products in order to find the right solution for you.